# TensorFlow object detection other shape of classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

in TensorFlow object detection API, is there any possibility to get other shape of recognized object than rectangle?

For example when I'm teaching my computer to recognize a forest, mostly it should be more useful to get some kind of polygon instead of rectangle.

Other thing is for example river, but polygon seems much easier than line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. This framework based on [Faster R-CNN: Towards Real-Time Object Detection with Region Proposal Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497) and [SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325) which train additional output of CNN for **bounding box** regression. Can you create CNN with some structure for detect polygon instead of bounding box? May be, but whis will another network.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you. 
And by the way, don't you know about some other tool or some shortcut to create a network similar to this one in object detection, but using bounding polygons?

Comment: Sorry I don't know networks which work polygon bounding. May be you should look at semantic segmentation task?

Comment: Okay, I will take a look. Thanks.
Maybe a good option could be implement SegNet into TensorFlow. Then it shouldn't be such a task to transform it to polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do it based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870.pdf)

There is an implementation [here](https://github.com/CharlesShang/FastMaskRCNN) but note that this is not related to the object detection API.

Answer (score 0):

You can segmentation techniques. For example, take a look at mask RCNN based methods [this link](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN)